# how can i make series of divs show up next to each other instead of on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

I have a form page with multiple div class called "inputs"
inside each `div` is the label of each form line and `input` for the form info

sample for one of them:

```html
<div class="inputs">
  <label for="ProductDesc:_">ProductDesc: </label>
  <input disabled="disabled" id="invoices_ProductDesc" name="invoices.ProductDesc" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="Storage charge SC160-0000059 - 5.0 HCTZ0044 2018">
</div>
<div class="inputs">
  <label for="SKU:_">SKU: </label>
  <input disabled="disabled" id="invoices_ProductSKU" name="invoices.ProductSKU" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Right now the display is something like:

> ProductDesc
>
> *info here*
>
> SKU
>
> *SKU here*

How can I make it so it becomes

> ProductDesc   SKU
>
> *info here*    *SKU here*

I tried using `float:right` on the input, and I also tried using `display:inline` but that didn't seem to work.

example of what i want https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlWIi.jpg

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. There must be some CSS or something else affecting it which you did not include in your question.

Comment: can you use bootstrap?

Comment: @Maccurt, yeeeaaaa, load the whole big library when you can just use one simple CSS property... First he should learn advanced HTML and CSS, then he can play with Bootstrap.

Comment: i want something like https://imgur.com/Evc0Hvs right now weyermann is right next to description and SKU is under description

Answer (score 2):

Wrap another div around them and set it up as a flexbox container by styling it as `display: flex`

Comment: this is by far the simplest solution. flexbox is quite simple to master and it will help you with most layout problems

Answer (score 1):

```
display: inline-block;
```

Should work fine, I think there is additional styling that is effecting the overall styling.

Working example:

https://codepen.io/5amdev/pen/povqrYm

Comment: nah thats not what i want i want something like https://imgur.com/Evc0Hvs

Comment: If you are looking to tabularize your data, then why not use a table...?  The code you provided vs your image example don't match up.